# VSCodeを初期化したが<Space>キーを押すと『{Space} was pressed. Wating for second key of chord』と出るのを解決したい

Tags: macos, vscode

#### 環境

MacOS Catalina (Ver10.15.6)
VSCode (Ver1.49.1) `~/.vscode` は削除してアプリも再インストールして初期化済

#### 問題点

タイトルの通りなのですが、スペースキーを押してもうんともすんとも言わず、代わりに『{Space} was pressed. Wating for second key of chord』と下に表記されるようになってしまいました。

また念の為『Keyboard Shortcuts』で"space"と検索してみましたが(初期化しているので当然)Defaultのままです。

ちなみに他のエディタ(PHPStromやneovim等)では問題なくスペースキーに反応してくれます。

上記の問題の解決策をご教示お願い致します。
※この情報が足りない！等ありましたらその旨も教えていただけると！

[2020/9/22]keybinding.jsonを追記
※keybinding.jsonはPreferences(cmd + ,)->keyboard shortcuts->右上のOpen keyboard shortcuts(JSON)より開く。

```
// Empty
[
  {
    "key": "space e",
    "command": "code-runner.run"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "-code-runner.run"
  }
]
```

Comment: 念のため、`keybidings.json` に何か書かれていないかチェックいただけないでしょうか。これはカスタムのキーバインド設定を記録するファイルで、Keyboard Shortcuts の画面にある右上のアイコンから開けます。

Comment: コメントだと見づらいので質問に追記致しました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

space から始まるカスタムのショートカットが存在するため、"Wating for second key of chord" が出てきています。

```
  {
    "key": "space e",
    "command": "code-runner.run"
  },
```

[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) という拡張機能のためのショートカットをデフォルトから変えた際にスペースキーを指定されたようです。このショートカットを使ってないのであれば上の記述を削除すれば直るかと思います。

Comment: 無事解決しました！！ありがとうございました！(.vimrcのキーバインドspace+eでシェルファイルの実行をしていたのを同じように適用しようとした設定が残ってしまっていたようです！本当に助かりました！)